# Fixed selector of Listview

Tags: java, android

I want to fixed my selector on a particular list item  I am doing this `LvQuestion.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(InsertIndexNo));
                        LvQuestion.setSelector(R.drawable.quiz_edit_text_colored);`  but this is not working.

Comment: Do you want to change the colour of selected item in listview

Comment: I want to fixed the background of a list item at index no 2

Comment: you want to change the background for list item index no 2 or all or for even rows in list item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer, you should override this method in get view in adapter,

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  
if (position == 2) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);  
}

return view;  
}
```

In this code for position 2 in listview colour capplied blue and cyan colour applied for remaining rows.